# Linking OpenCV (with Cuda) with C++ code implementing CUDA function return linking error

Tags: macos, opencv, cuda, linker, linker-errors

I have compiled OpenCV (2.4.6.1) from source with CUDA (6.0) enabled on OS X Mavericks (10.9.3).

Now I would like to create my own image processing functions using mixture of OpenCV and CUDA. Let's take a simple example where we have an OpenCV Mat and want to do something on each element and want to speed this up by parallelizing this using CUDA. In our example we only print out the value of each Mat element. Not realistic but good enough to show the concept.

**CUDA header file:** `print.cuh`

```
#ifndef __PRINT_CUH__
#define __PRINT_CUH__

void print(const unsigned char * pixels, const int N);

#endif
```

**CUDA source file:** `print.cu`

```
#include <stdio.h>

// The device version
__global__ void cuda_print(const unsigned char * pixels, const int N)
{
    int tidX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if( tidX >= N ) {
        return;
    }

    printf("pixel value @ %d = %d\n", tidX, pixels[tidX]);
}

// The host version
void print(const unsigned char * pixels, const int N) {
    int num_blocks = 10;
    int num_threads = 128;

    unsigned char * d_pixels;
    cudaMalloc( &d_pixels, sizeof(char) * N );
    cudaMemcpy( d_pixels, pixels, sizeof(char)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cuda_print<<<num_blocks, num_threads>>>(d_pixels, N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // The above call is asynchronous, wait until it
                             // finishes before exiting the program!

}
```

**C++ code including OpenCV and our own CUDA code:** `main.cpp`

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include "print.cuh"

int main(int argc, char ** argv )
{
    cv::Mat m(100,1,CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));

    print(m.ptr(0), m.rows);

    return 0;
}
```

We want to compile our own CUDA code into a shared library and include it in our main

**CMAKE setup:** `CMakeLists.txt`

```
# CUDA CMAKE TEST 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# project name
project(CUDA_CMAKE)

# find dependencies 
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

# this is necessary on OS X since CUDA only support the older libstdc++
IF(APPLE)
    SET(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang CACHE FILEPATH "Setting clang as the CUDA compiler" FORCE)
    SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-Xcompiler -stdlib=libstdc++; -Xlinker -stdlib=libstdc++; -arch=sm_20" CACHE STRING "Setting NVCC compiler flags" FORCE)
ENDIF()

# build a shared library with our CUDA code
CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY(cudaPrint 
    SHARED
    print.cu
)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(cudaPrint
    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
)

# build the C++ code and link with the CUDA code
ADD_EXECUTABLE(cuda_test 
    main.cpp 
)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(cuda_test
    cudaPrint ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

The first step of the build works fine and the cudaPrint.dylib is generated. 
However, when trying to build the executable I get the following linking error:

```
make all 
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:29 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target cuda_test because
  there is a cycle in the constraint graph:

    dir 0 is [/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/lib]
      dir 1 must precede it due to runtime library [libcudart.dylib]
    dir 1 is [/usr/local/cuda/lib]
      dir 0 must precede it due to runtime library [libcudart.dylib]

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/navid/proj/CUDA/test_cuda_opencv/build
[ 50%] Built target cudaPrint
Linking CXX executable cuda_test
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/lib' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [cuda_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It looks like this error has something to do with OpenCV also including CUDA libraries. I am not sure but I have a work around for this which I am posting below.

Answer (score 3):

So it appears that the linking error is due to passing `libopencv_ts` to the linker through  `${OpenCV_LIBS}`, because `FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)` adds all OpenCV libraries to the `${OpenCV_LIBS}` variable.

If `libopencv_ts` is **not required**, a simple work-around is to specify which OpenCV libraries we explicitly want when we ask `CMAKE` to find the package, e.g. `FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS core highgui cuda)`.

I don't know why `libopencv_ts` is creating this cycling error and how to get around it.